# Selecting Objectify data from the Google DataStore using GSQL in the Developer Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an Objectify entity called `UserEntity` which contains an object called `user`. I want to dump all the last sync times and some other data from my user objects to do a bit of analysis. I'm trying to do this in the Developers Console using GSQL but can't work out how to get the results I want.

The query below works to get everything

```
SELECT * FROM UserEntity
```

Using this query get's all the keys

```
SELECT __key__ FROM UserEntity
```

This returns nothing, saying `No data was found.`

```
SELECT user FROM UserEntity
```

But I can't work out how to (or if I can) select individual properties from objects. Is it possible to achieve this in the Developer Console, or shall I just write some code to do it?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like

```
SELECT user.synctime, user.currentLevel FROM UserEntity
```

Stripped `UserEntity` class below

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class UserEntity extends WordBuzzEntity {
    @Id
    private String facebookId;
    public User user = new User(null);
    private HashMap<String, Date> accessTokens = new HashMap<String, Date>();
}
```

Comment: Is `user` an embedded entity? If you just `SELECT *` how is the `user` property shown in the console?  And are you using the old (appengine.google.com) or new (console.developer.google.com) console?

Comment: @tx802 I've added the structure of the `UserEntity` class to the question. I'm using the new console. When I do `SELECT *` I get 3 columns showing in the console called `Name/ID`, `accessTokens` and `user`

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the datastore fundamentally works. The datastore is a key/value store with some extra indexing. The values are serialized protobufs. Generally speaking, you load entities whole and cannot pick/choose the parts you want.

There is some extra cleverness that the datastore can perform, selecting data directly out of an index rather than loading the protobuf value. The most obvious is a keys-only query (the key is always part of every index). More sophisticated is a "projection" query which *looks* like SQL select at first glance, but really is quite a different animal and requires you to maintain special indexes. However, that is an advanced performance optimization that you should not pursue unless you *really* know what you are doing. Start with the simple model of loading whole entities.